# noise and classical bits (measurements ) in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-operation, simulation, noise

I am using qiskit and LocalNoisePass to add custom noise to the gates. But there is a problem when there are classical bits in the circuits. The localNoisePass give this error

```
Noise must be an instruction without clbits.
```

For instance, I have one Instruction containing measurements: Instruction(name='measure', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=1, params=[]) and it fails. This will definitely throw an error if there is some conditional statements depending on measurements in circuits.

What are the possible solutions?